# How can I find a dynamic-directory in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Files:

```
 /home/asite.com/httpdocs/dynamic-subdir/.htaccess
 /home/asite.com/httpdocs/dynamic-subdir/index.php
```

Wants:

```
Find the desired directory. (dynamic-subdir)
```

Desired directory is "dynamic-subdir".

```
RewriteEngine On

#Forward
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . {dynamic-subdir}index.php$1 [L]
```

Request:

```
asite.com/dynamic-subdir/apage/asubpage/
```

Directed page:

```
asite.com/dynamic-subdir/index.php?apage/asubpage/
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your RewriteRule in your htaccess from:

```
RewriteRule . {dynamic-subdir}index.php$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,R]
```

And remove the `RewriteBase /`. You can then place this .htaccess in any directory and it will rewrite **/dynamic-subdir/apage/asubpage/** to **/dynamic-subdir/index.php?apage/asubpage/** or any *dynamic-subdir* that you place the .htaccess in.

Comment: This sulition not working. Directing to http://127.0.0.1/D:/... or http://127.0.0.1/index.php . htaccess is in dynamic-subdir/.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Request:

```
asite.com/dynamic-subdir/apage/asubpage/
```

Directed page:

```
asite.com/dynamic-subdir/index.php?apage/asubpage/
```

The rules should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/(.*) index.php?$2 [QSA,L]
```

Please tell me if it works ;)